# Powershell document.getElementbyID - doesn't pull right information

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, getelementbyid

I got a little powershell problem troubling me for quite a while now.

Im trying to get information from a RSS site. I download the XML and go through it. I just want certain stuff from it. That for I use .document.getElementByID().outerText

The problem is that somehow it pulls the first information correctly but after that everything fails he just picks random text or just keeps the one text from the beginning without refreshing the variable. Also Powershell ISE says "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." randomly.

Here is my code:

```
<#
AUTHOR: KOCH,MICHAEL [GRE-IT]
DESCRIPTION: RSS READER
DATE: 28.06.17
DATE LAST WRITTEN: 19.07.17
LAST CHANGE: 
#>

$debug = 1 #DEBUG

$receiver="A@MailAdress.com" 
$sender="A@MailAdress.com" 
$smtp="A.SMTP.SERVER"
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

$path_config = "C:\RSS\Zoll\config.txt"
$output = "C:\RSS\Zoll\meldung.html"
$output_edit_path = "C:\RSS\Zoll\meldung_edit.html"
$nmbr=0
$count=0

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.zoll.de/SiteGlobals/Functions/RSSFeed/DE/RSSNewsfeed/RSSZollImFokus.xml' -OutFile C:\RSS\Zoll\meldungen.xml -ErrorAction Stop
[xml]$content = Get-Content C:\RSS\Zoll\meldungen.xml
$feed = $content.rss.channel
$tag = @()

if($lines=Get-Content $path_config | Measure-Object -Line) #gets the number of lines
{ 
    while($count -ne $lines.Lines)
    {
        if($entrys=(Get-Content $path_config)[$nmbr]) #gets the entrys from config.txt and goes through line by line
        {
            $entrys >> $tag[$nmbr]

            if ($debug -eq 1)
            {
                Write-Output "$tag[$nmbr]"
                Write-Output "$entrys"
                Write-Output "$count"
            }
        }
        $count++
        $nmbr++ #jumps into the next line
    }
}

$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"

Foreach($msg in $feed.Item)
{
    $link = ($msg.link)
    $subject = ($msg.title)

    $ie.navigate("$link")

    #$return = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $link -OutFile "C:\RSS\Zoll\link.html"

    $return = $ie.document
    $innertext = $return.documentElement.document.getElementById("main").outerText

    $body = $innertext#.Replace('Ä', '&Auml;')
    <#
    $body = $innertext.Replace('ä', '&auml;')
    $body = $innertext.Replace('Ö', '&Ouml;')
    $body = $innertext.Replace('ö', '&ouml;') 
    $body = $innertext.Replace('Ü', '&Uuml;')
    $body = $innertext.Replace('ü', '&uuml;')
    $body = $innertext.Replace('ß', '&szlig;')
    #>
        if ($debug -eq 1)
        {
            Write-Output "Subject $subject"
            Write-Output "Tag $tag"
            Write-Output "Link $link"
            Write-Output $body
            #exit
        }

        if($link -match "Zigaretten") #searchs in the <link> for the string "Zigaretten" 
        {
           if($subject -match $tag) #searches for the specified tag in config.txt !!! only one argument per line !!!
           {
               if($mail = Send-MailMessage -From "$sender" -To "$receiver" -Subject "Zoll Meldung: $subject" -Body "$body" -SmtpServer "$smtp" -BodyAsHtml -encoding $encoding)
               {
                   if($debug -eq 1)
                   {
                       Write-Output "$tag"
                       Write-Output "Send. Tag = $tag"
                   }
                       Write-Output "Send."
               }
           }
       }
        else
        {
         Write-Host "Empty."
        }
}

$ie.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie)
Remove-Variable ie
```

Comment: I don't think all your downstream links have a 'main' element. For example, Google.com does and Yahoo.com does not. The web side of this is out of my realm a bit so I don't know if that is a standard thing or not but I would wrap your getElementById in some error checking to see if you actually got something before you proceed.

Comment: I would also suggest you do away with the IE comObject altogether and just replace it with Invoke-WebRequest.. You can do this:
`$html = invoke-webrequest "http://www.yourpath.here"`
and then use the parsedHTML property in the same way you are doing with the IE document:
`$html.parsedHtml.getElementsById("main")`

Comment: Program now throws exception at every pulled article 

Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
At C:\Users\mkoch\Desktop\RSSreader.ps1:61 char:5
+     $innertext = $return.parsedHtml.getElementById("main").outerText
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException

Comment: Also still wont work.

Comment: In order to help further I would need to see what you are actually targeting. Is it publicly accessible? If not, can you perform the `invoke-webrequest` method and then post the contents of it? Please check if data should be scrubbed before posting.
`(invoke-webrequest -uri $link).rawcontent`

Comment: It is public. I now got the answer myself I post it as answer and mark it. You can see it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added a wait if busy loop to make sure IE loads the full html document. Thats the solution of the problem ! :)

```
<#
AUTHOR: KOCH,MICHAEL [GRE-IT]
DESCRIPTION: RSS READER
DATE: 28.06.17
DATE LAST WRITTEN: 20.07.17
LAST CHANGE: ADDED WAIT IF BUSY ! 
#>

$debug = 0 #DEBUG

$receiver="A@MailAdress.de" 
$sender="A@MailAdress.de" 
$smtp="A.SMTP.SERVER"
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

$path_config = "C:\RSS\Zoll\config.txt"
$output = "C:\RSS\Zoll\meldung.html"
$output_edit_path = "C:\RSS\Zoll\meldung_edit.html"
$nmbr=0
$count=0

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.zoll.de/SiteGlobals/Functions/RSSFeed/DE/RSSNewsfeed/RSSZollImFokus.xml' -OutFile C:\RSS\Zoll\meldungen.xml -ErrorAction Stop
[xml]$content = Get-Content C:\RSS\Zoll\meldungen.xml
$feed = $content.rss.channel
$tag = @()

if($lines=Get-Content $path_config | Measure-Object -Line) #gets the number of lines
{ 
    while($count -ne $lines.Lines)
    {
        if($entrys=(Get-Content $path_config)[$nmbr]) #gets the entrys from config.txt and goes through line by line
        {
            $entrys >> $tag[$nmbr]

            if ($debug -eq 1)
            {
                Write-Output "$tag[$nmbr]"
                Write-Output "$entrys"
                Write-Output "$count"
            }
        }
        $count++
        $nmbr++ #jumps into the next line
    }
}

$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application #creates new ComObject IE

Foreach($msg in $feed.Item)
{
    $link = ($msg.link)
    $subject = ($msg.title)

    if ($debug -eq 1)
    {
        $ie.visible = $true
    }

    $ie.navigate("$link") #navigate with Internetexplorer to the website

    while ($ie.busy -and $ie.ReadyState -ne 4){ sleep -Milliseconds 200 } # if getting the website from IE.navigate is still .busy wait 200 milliseconds

    $return = $ie.document 

    $innertext = $return.documentelement.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("main").outerText #gets the outer text from the div with the element ID "main"

    while ($innertext.busy -and $innertext.ReadyState -ne 4){ sleep -Milliseconds 200 } # if getting Text is .busy wait 200 milliseconds

    $body = $innertext

    if ($debug -eq 1)
    {
        Write-Output "Subject $subject"
        Write-Output "Tag $tag"
        Write-Output "Link $link"
        Write-Output "INNERTEXT $innertext"
        Write-Output "BODY $body"
        #exit
    }

    if($link -match "Zigaretten") #searchs in the <link> for the string "Zigaretten" 
    {
        if($subject -match $tag) #searches for the specified tag in config.txt !!! only one argument per line !!!
        {
            if($mail = Send-MailMessage -From "$sender" -To "$receiver" -Subject "Zoll Meldung: $subject" -Body "$body" -SmtpServer "$smtp" -BodyAsHtml -encoding $encoding)
            {
                Write-Output "Send."
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Empty."
    }
}

$ie.Quit()                                                               #----| 
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie)          #    ---> Quits the Internet Explorer Session otherwise there are to many IE.exe open and no more ID's left
Remove-Variable ie
```